# How to edit appsettings in Azure pipeline?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-devops

I'm trying to edit appsettings (.net) in azure pipelines, it's for differents environments(production, development, etc..)
For example I want to change this value in appsettings:

```
"NodeServiceSettings":{
"Api": "http://localhost:4500/"
}
```

I tried the nexts things:

In pipeline > variables:

[image]

In app service configuration:

[image]

But nothing worked. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Your continuous delivery tool shouldn't be responsible for defining application configuration -- this tightly couples your continuous delivery tool to your application deployment process. Your application configuration settings should be stored in keyvault or Azure App Configuration, or defined in your IaC templates.

Comment: I added in the second photo in my App Service Configuration but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a section in release pipelines to do exactly this, the section can be found here, but it is strongly recommended to use central Azure App Configuration and not local app settings so you can re use setitngs across applications.

[image: App Settings in Release Pipeline]